# Set a timezone other than the system timezone for specific applications

Tags: windows-10, time-zone

Is it possible in Windows 10 to set an application to run using a timezone different than the system's timezone?

For example, the system timezone is GMT-5:00 (EST) but I want an application to run in GMT+9:00 (JPN) without having to switch the system timezone to GMT+9:00 before launching the app.

Comment: Is it possible, yes, an application can display the system time in any number of ways but unless it provides a way to change it the end user cannot change how the application functions

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for your reply! I believe what you're proposing is for the application to have a timezone changing functionality built into it. What I was asking was for a means for the OS to provide a timezone to application that's different than the system timezone, without the application even being aware of it.

Comment: I am saying the programmer of the application can implement displaying the system time however they want but the user is at the mercy of how that’s done.  Unless the application provides a method what you want is not possible due to how the program was written (it’s possible to grab the system time and hard code a time zone adjustment).  What you want is not realistically

Comment: May I ask which specific application(s) you are trying to affect?